# ngResource default parameters

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use my variable 'selectedDate' in my rest calls, but it always uses the old one, even after setting a new value with the 'setSelectedDate()' function

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($resource) {

    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var selectedDate = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;

    return {
        getSelectedDate : function(){
            return selectedDate;
        },
        setSelectedDate : function(newDate){
            selectedDate = newDate;
            console.log(selectedDate); // My setSelectedDate works well because I can see the new value in the console
        },

        // The selectedDate always return the first value (the new Date() ), and not the updated date
        Meal: $resource('/rest/food/meal', {date : selectedDate, mealId: '@mealId'}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                params : {date : selectedDate}

            }          
        }),
    }
});
```

It does work if I manually set the parameters like this, for example in my controller :

```
FoodService.setSelectedDate(newDate);
$scope.meals = FoodService.Meal.query(FoodService.getSelectedDate());
```

But I would like my service to automatically use the 'selectedDate' variable, and just have to call :

```
FoodService.setSelectedDate(newDate);
$scope.meals = FoodService.Meal.query();
```

But it always use the old (first) date and not the updated one..

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

I tried as params, and in the $resource after '/rest/food/meal' the following :
- {date : getSelectedDate} => ReferenceError: getSelectedDate is not defined 
- {date : getSelectedDate()} => same 
- {date : this.getSelectedDate()} => TypeError: Object # has no method 'getSelectedDate'

And finally the one which should work..
-{date : selectedDate)} => Does work but always use the first selectedDate I defined in the first place, but not the updated date

Comment: Did you see the new function `getSelectedDate()` that is added to the factory? You can rename that if it is getting confused with the api name.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to rename my function but I still got the same problem.
What exactly shoud I call in my params ? getSelectedDate(), this.getSelectedDate(), selectedDate, others.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory needs to be modified as below:

```
app.factory('FoodService', function ($resource) {
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var selectedDate = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;

    function blahBlahFunction() {
      return selectedDate;
    }

    return {
        getSelectedDate : function(){
            return blahBlahFunction();
        },
        setSelectedDate : function(newDate){
            selectedDate = newDate;
            console.log(selectedDate);
        },

        Meal: $resource('/rest/food/meal', {date : blahBlahFunction, 
                                            mealId: '@mealId'}, { 
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                params : { date : blahBlahFunction }
            }          
        }),
    }
});
```

**Note:**
params is the default pre-bound parameters. In order to provide parameters dynamically that element has to be wrapped in a function and the function to be used as param.

This almost defies the notion of default param, I think **without** the above changes the call would have been as:

```
FoodService.Meal.query({date: "12/11/2014"});
```

Refer this [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/Plx7sqRA3Jq9KItA1yYX?p=preview) for details. Look for an error with the URL in console in dev tool. Should say:

```
GET http://run.plnkr.co/rest/food/meal?date=12%2F11%2F2014 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: You are right about the : FoodService.Meal.query({date: "12/11/2014"}); with my code

but I sill can't be able to use my 'selectedDate' as default parameter.
I tried as params and in the $resource after '/rest/food/meal' 
- {date : getSelectedDate} => ReferenceError: getSelectedDate is not defined
- {date : getSelectedDate()} => same
- {date : this.getSelectedDate()} => TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getSelectedDate'

and the one which should work
-{date : selectedDate)} => Always use the first selectedDate I defined in the first place, but not the updated date

Comment: Refer this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Plx7sqRA3Jq9KItA1yYX?p=preview) and look for an error with the url in console in dev tool.

Comment: Once again, look for the new function I added in the factory.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It does work now, I'm really sorry, I missed your function when I read your comment...
Why do I need to add a second function outside of the "return" ? And why don't we use getSelectedDate() with the tokens () ?

Thanks again..

Comment: Have a look at my notes in answer. You cannot get latest date for default parameters unless it is defined as a function. If only it is a function, it gets executed every time a query is fired. Also look at the updated answer, does `blahBlahFunction` name looks good and vivid?

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is clear now. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm not a native speaker so I had some issues to understand properly..

Comment: Not a problem at all. Glad it was helpful.